# OpenID connect together AWS Cognito

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to get myself authenticated with a custom openID connect provider.
For retrieving my JWT token I use the following library:

https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-iOS

I have a custom OpenIDAuthHandler class. 
For retrieving my JWT token I have this function that works with the AppAuth library:

```
  func getToken(tokenCompletion: AWSTaskCompletionSource<NSString>) {
        let issuer = URL(string: config.issuerURL)
        let clientID = config.clientID
        let redirectURL = URL(string: config.redirectURL)

        log.debug("Fetching configuration for issuer: \(issuer!)")

        // discovers endpoints
        OIDAuthorizationService.discoverConfiguration(forIssuer: issuer!) { configuration, error in
            if configuration == nil {
                log.debug("Error retrieving discovery document: \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
                return
            }

            log.debug("Got configuration: \(configuration!)")

            // builds authentication request
            let request = OIDAuthorizationRequest(configuration: configuration!,
                                                  clientId: clientID,
                                                  scopes: ["openid", "offline_access", "profile", "IPTVUserID"],
                                                  redirectURL: redirectURL!,
                                                  responseType: OIDResponseTypeCode,
                                                  additionalParameters: nil)

            // performs authentication request
            guard let rootVC = self.application.keyWindow?.rootViewController else { return }
            guard let delegate = self.application.appDelegate as? AppDelegate else { return }
            log.debug("Initiating authorization request with scope: \(request.scope!)")

            delegate.currentAuthorizationFlow = OIDAuthState.authState(byPresenting: request, presenting: rootVC) { authState, error in
                if authState != nil {
                    log.debug("Got authorization tokens. Access token: \(authState!.lastTokenResponse!.accessToken!)")
                    guard let token = authState?.lastTokenResponse?.accessToken else {
                        tokenCompletion.set(error: NSError(domain: "OIDC Login",
                                                           code: -1,
                                                           userInfo: ["Unable to get OIDC token": "Details about your error"]))
                        return
                    }
                    self.defaults.set(token, forKey: .accessToken)
                    tokenCompletion.set(result: token as NSString)

                } else {
                    log.debug("Authorization error: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
                    tokenCompletion.set(error: NSError(domain: "OIDC Login",
                                                       code: -1,
                                                       userInfo: ["Unable to get OIDC token": "Details about your error"]))
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Note: From this one I get a valid JWT token back, so this part is working I assume.

Further more I have a `OpenIDAuthHandler class` that implements the `AWSCognitoCredentialsProviderHelper` protocol.

```
override func token() -> AWSTask<NSString> {
        let completion = AWSTaskCompletionSource<NSString>()
        getToken(tokenCompletion: completion)

        let task1 =  completion.task.continueOnSuccessWith { (task) -> AWSTask<NSString> in
            return AWSTask(result: task.result!)
        }

        if let task2 = task1 as? AWSTask<NSString> {
            return task2
        } else {
            log.error("Something went wrong with \(task1)")
            return AWSTask()
        }
    }

    override func logins () -> AWSTask<NSDictionary> {
        let token = self.defaults.string(forKey: .accessToken)
        if token == nil {
            let accessTokenTask = self.token()
            guard let accessToken = accessTokenTask.result else {
                return AWSTask(error: NSError(domain: self.config.issuerURL, code: -1, userInfo: [self.config.issuerURL: "No current access token"]))
            }
            return AWSTask(result: ["cbo.eu.auth0.com": accessToken])

        } else {
            if let token = token {
                return AWSTask(result: ["cbo.eu.auth0.com": token])
            }
            return AWSTask(error: NSError(domain: self.config.issuerURL, code: -1, userInfo: [self.config.issuerURL: "No current access token"]))
        }
    }
```

Now here is where the problem is coming. I'm trying to get my accesskey, secret key and session key back with AWS cognito with the following piece of code:

```
 let credentialsProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType: .EUWest1, identityProvider: self.openIDAuthHandler)
    let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: .EUWest1, credentialsProvider: credentialsProvider)
    AWSServiceManager.default().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration

    credentialsProvider.credentials().continueWith(block: { (task) -> AnyObject? in
        if task.error != nil {
            log.error("Error 1: " + task.error!.localizedDescription)
        } else {
            // the task result will contain the identity id
            let credentials = task.result!
            log.debug("access key: \(credentials.accessKey)")
            log.debug("secret key: \(credentials.secretKey)")
            log.debug("session key: \(credentials.sessionKey ?? "No session key available")")
        }
        return task
    })
```

But for some reason or another I keep getting the following error:

```
com.amazonaws.AWSCognitoIdentityErrorDomain error 8.
```

Comment: hi, @Steaphann did you solve this? any suggestions? thanks.